# Using pipes with multiple clients

Tags: c

I am trying to program the server side of a groupchat system using C whilst my friend is programming the client side.   For each client connection the server receives, it forks a child process so as to handle the client and continue accepting any possibly further clients.

The server is required to send a list of all online users(connected clients) to each of the current connected clients and for this reason I have used pipes.  Basically, when a child process is created, it receives come information from the client through a socket and sends such information to the parent, which is keeping a list of all the clients, through a pipe.  This list has to be updated every time a client makes a change like starts chatting or disconnects.  For example if  a client disconnects then the child sends a message to the parent through the pipe and the parent makes the necessary operations to the list so that it gets updated.  Note that the pipe is created for each and every new connection.

My problem is that if for example I receive 3 connections one after another, and the 2nd child disconnects, the parent is not reading the information from the pipe since such parent has a different pipe from the 2nd child.  (Remember that a new pipe has been created because a 3rd connection has been made).  How can I go about solving this problem?

I have also tried creating one common pipe but if I don't close the pipe before reading/writing I get an error and if I do close them I get a segmentation fault when the second client connects since the pipe would be closed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated because I have been searching for hours to no avail.

Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest looking into something like `epoll` so that it is easier for you to maintain all of your concurrent connections in a single process at scale.  Then you don't need to talk through pipes and can talk directly to sockets in an async manner.

Comment: Indeed, you should use sockets and asynchronous IO instead of pipes. (You may want to build upon this library in your implementation: https://developer.gnome.org/glib)

Comment: Will I be still be able to keep a common list between all the clients?

Comment: @moooeeeep: What is the benefit of sockets over pipes?  They're both a file descriptor (initially two with a pipe, but you close the end you aren't using); they both block waiting for I/O; they're both amenable to `select()`, `poll()`, `epoll()` calls...

Comment: Why make it so complicated when shared memory and a mutex will do the job.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler In that case, probably it's just that I prefer bidirectional IO channels for reasons of convenience.

Answer (score 0):

The parent server process knows when a child is created because it creates the child.  It can tell when a child dies by setting a SIGCLD signal handler so it is notified when a child does die.  The N<sup>th</sup> child has N-1 pipes to close — those going to the other children (unless some of the children have died).  The parent process closes the write end of the pipes it creates; the child process closes the read end of the pipes it inherits (which leaves it with a socket to the client and the write end of the pipe created for it to communicate with the parent).

If you need to know when a child starts communicating with a client, then you need to send a message down the pipe from the child to the parent.  It is not so obvious how to tell when the child stops communicating — how long needs to elapse before you declare that the child is idle again?

In the parent, you end up polling in some shape or form (`select()`, `poll()`, `epoll()`) on the listening socket and all the read pipes.  When some activity occurs, the parent wakes up and responds appropriately.  It's a feasible design as long as it doesn't have to scale to thousands or more clients.  It requires some care, notably in closing enough file descriptors.

You say:

> My problem is that if for example I receive 3 connections one after another, and the 2nd child disconnects, the parent is not reading the information from the pipe since such parent has a different pipe from the 2nd child. (Remember that a new pipe has been created because a 3rd connection has been made). How can I go about solving this problem?

The parent should have an array of open file descriptors (pipes open for reading to various children), along with an indication of which child (PID) is on the other end of the pipe.  The parent will close the pipe when it gets EOF on the pipe, or when it is notified that the child has died (via `waitpid()` or a relative).  The polling mechanism will tell you when a pipe is closed, at least indirectly (you will be told the file descriptor won't block, and then you get the EOF — zero bytes read).

In your scenario, the parent has one listening socket open, plus 3 read file descriptors for the pipes to the 3 children (plus standard input, output and error, and maybe syslog).

Although you could use a single pipe from all the children, it is much trickier to handle.  You'd have to identify which child wrote each message in the message, ensuring that the message is written atomically by the child.  The parent has to be able to tell how much to read at any point so as not to be confused.  The advantage of a single pipe is that there is less file descriptor manipulation to do for the polling system call; it also scales indefinitely (no running out of file descriptors).

In neither case should you run into problems with core dumps.